# Slow remote-desktop connection on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm using remote desktop through a VPN connection to work on a remote computer.

Since I update my PCs from windows XP to windows 7, the performance of the remote desktop connection is dramatically worse than before. For example, when working in Visual Studio, whenever I do something (like compiling) I can see how the user interface (toolbar buttons, file-lists, etc) is redrawn several times (which takes several seconds). I never noticed such a slow update of the UI when I was using XP on both computers.

Are there any settings (network, remote desktop, etc) that could be resonsible for the performce loss in remote desktop? Any ideas how to improve remote desktop performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no difference in network e.g. you were not using VPN before and you are now - I think that it could be that settings in the "experience" tab have been changed.

Take a look here as there are items you can disable in order to speed up the remote connection.

[image]

Comment: There is no difference in network setup. But indeed, the "Desktop composition" setting of the Remote Desktop connection makes a huge difference. Turned it off, and it's much better now. Thanks.